# How can I find the amount of video Ram installed through a WMI call?

Tags: wmi

Does anyone know how to get the Video Ram of a PC from a WMI call?

I've seen calls to the Win32_VideoController management object's AdapterRAM property, but that only gives the system memory, and is not representative of the video RAM at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it was the adapter RAM returned, and through an unfortunate coincidence, the wrong conversion was used and gave the system RAM...on two different systems. Thanks for pushing us to look again.

For what it's worth, in a C# WinForms app:

```
int _ram = 0;

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select AdapterRAM from Win32_VideoController");

foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
   var ram = mo.Properties["AdapterRAM"].Value as UInt32?;

   if (ram.HasValue)
   {
      _ram = ((int)ram/1048576);
   }
}
```

Comment: i have amd 7870 2GB and it return a negative valor -2048 why?

Comment: Because the parentheses are set wrong. Should be: _ram = (int)(ram/1048576);

Comment: I wonder what happens to this silly uint32 when someone owns a GPU with 4 GiB or more of RAM

Comment: Then it will return 4 GiB which renders this interface kinda useless and forcing me now to find another way to get the correct value...

Answer (score 3):

From [The Microsoft Technet Script Center Script Repository](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/) under 'Hardware' then 'Video and Display' then 'List Video Controller Properties'.

I would imagine you might have to work out something between AdapterRAM and 'VideoMemoryType'

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_VideoController")

For Each objItem in colItems
    For Each strCapability in objItem.AcceleratorCapabilities
        Wscript.Echo "Accelerator Capability: " & strCapability
    Next
    Wscript.Echo "Adapter Compatibility: " & objItem.AdapterCompatibility
    Wscript.Echo "Adapter DAC Type: " & objItem.AdapterDACType
    Wscript.Echo "Adapter RAM: " & objItem.AdapterRAM
    Wscript.Echo "Availability: " & objItem.Availability
    Wscript.Echo "Color Table Entries: " & objItem.ColorTableEntries
    Wscript.Echo "Current Bits Per Pixel: " & objItem.CurrentBitsPerPixel
    Wscript.Echo "Current Horizontal Resolution: " & _
        objItem.CurrentHorizontalResolution
    Wscript.Echo "Current Number of Colors: " & objItem.CurrentNumberOfColors
    Wscript.Echo "Current Number of Columns: " & objItem.CurrentNumberOfColumns
    Wscript.Echo "Current Number of Rows: " & objItem.CurrentNumberOfRows
    Wscript.Echo "Current Refresh Rate: " & objItem.CurrentRefreshRate
    Wscript.Echo "Current Scan Mode: " & objItem.CurrentScanMode
    Wscript.Echo "Current Vertical Resolution: " & _
        objItem.CurrentVerticalResolution
    Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
    Wscript.Echo "Device ID: " & objItem.DeviceID
    Wscript.Echo "Device Specific Pens: " & objItem.DeviceSpecificPens
    Wscript.Echo "Dither Type: " & objItem.DitherType
    Wscript.Echo "Driver Date: " & objItem.DriverDate
    Wscript.Echo "Driver Version: " & objItem.DriverVersion
    Wscript.Echo "ICM Intent: " & objItem.ICMIntent
    Wscript.Echo "ICM Method: " & objItem.ICMMethod
    Wscript.Echo "INF Filename: " & objItem.InfFilename
    Wscript.Echo "INF Section: " & objItem.InfSection
    Wscript.Echo "Installed Display Drivers: " & _
        objItem.InstalledDisplayDrivers
    Wscript.Echo "Maximum Memory Supported: " & objItem.MaxMemorySupported
    Wscript.Echo "Maximum Number Controlled: " & objItem.MaxNumberControlled
    Wscript.Echo "Maximum Refresh Rate: " & objItem.MaxRefreshRate
    Wscript.Echo "Minimum Refresh Rate: " & objItem.MinRefreshRate
    Wscript.Echo "Monochrome: " & objItem.Monochrome
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    Wscript.Echo "Number of Color Planes: " & objItem.NumberOfColorPlanes
    Wscript.Echo "Number of Video Pages: " & objItem.NumberOfVideoPages
    Wscript.Echo "PNP Device ID: " & objItem.PNPDeviceID
    Wscript.Echo "Reserved System Palette Entries: " & _
        objItem.ReservedSystemPaletteEntries
    Wscript.Echo "Specification Version: " & objItem.SpecificationVersion
    Wscript.Echo "System Palette Entries: " & objItem.SystemPaletteEntries
    Wscript.Echo "Video Architecture: " & objItem.VideoArchitecture
    Wscript.Echo "Video Memory Type: " & objItem.VideoMemoryType
    Wscript.Echo "Video Mode: " & objItem.VideoMode
    Wscript.Echo "Video Mode Description: " & objItem.VideoModeDescription
    Wscript.Echo "Video Processor: " & objItem.VideoProcessor
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select AdapterRAM from 

    Win32_VideoController");

                    foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
                    {                            

                        double MemorySize = Convert.ToDouble(mo.Properties["AdapterRAM"].Value) / 1048576;

                        return MemorySize.ToString();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We already went down the path of the AdapterRAM property, but that was only giving us the system memory, which has nothing to do with the Video Ram.  Is there another way of getting the video ram?

Comment: Quite a few integrated chipsets use system memory as video memory; are you running your test on a system with a real graphics card or integrated graphics?

Comment: I thought that too... We test this code also on a macbook pro that has an integrated graphics card.  Still the same behavior