# How to get VRAM usage in C#?

Tags: c#, gpu, vram

I need to measure VRAM usage to use in my program, but I'm not finding anything about this.

It can be GPU Usage aswell.

It would be great if I could use the same tool/code/wtv for AMD and NVIDIA, but I need AMD much more than NVIDIA.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341243/how-can-i-find-the-amount-of-video-ram-installed-through-a-wmi-call?

Comment: Sounds great, you can do it

Comment: @j.i.h. That's different. In that question he wanted the VRAM size, I want the VRAM usage at the moment.